# Javascript sort() not alphabetizing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

```
var ccArray = [];
ccArray = $("input:checkbox[name='multiselect_ddlCC']").sort();
```

I can tell that I get the values I need in the array, but after sort() runs the array order is changed but not alphabetically. I get something like ENG, ATL, NAS, CLT, BIM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking to sort DOM elements or checkbox values? You're doing the former at the moment.

Comment: You are not sorting the right thing. You are sorting elements. (For questions about HTML/CSS/JS you should give an example with a [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen) It's easier to help you :)

Comment: I see, I don't suppose there is a way to select the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to sort the DOM elements and re-append them.

```
var $els = $("input:checkbox[name='multiselect_ddlCC']");

var $sorted = $($els.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.value > b.value;
}));

$els.replaceWith($sorted);
```

**Edit:** Just tested `replaceWith` and it didn't work, my bad. This works fine:

```
$els.each(function(i) {
  $(this).after($sorted.eq(i));
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/agizoy/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually compare the input values, and since they are strings you have to use `<` or `>` as subtraction won't work properly:

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    if ($(a).val() < $(b).val()) {
       return -1;
    }
    else {
       return 1;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdMBW/

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting jQuery-wrapped HTML elements, not strings.  Who knows which of those comes before another in sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

And if you just wanted a sorted list of selected checkbox values:

```
var values = [];
$('input:checkbox[name='multiselect_ddlCC']:checked').each(function(i,e){
  values.push(e.value);
});
var sortedValues = values.sort();
```

[example included](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/MAzS9/)

Answer (score 0):

That should works :

```
jQuery.map(ccArray, function(item) { return item.value }).sort()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to sort their values by using the .val() rather than the elements themselves.

```
var ccArray = [];
ccArray = $("input:checkbox[name='multiselect_ddlCC']").val().sort();
```

Comment: .val() doesn't give you are an array of the values of each element.  It just gives the value of the first.