# sort() does not work

Tags: javascript, sorting

I use sort() to sort my table but I do not understand why it does not work. you have an idea ?

```js
var tab = [5, 15, 17, 3, 8, 11, 28, 6, 55, 7];
tab = tab.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
  $("p").append(" ", tab[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1423tLwd/

Comment: This question doesn't work? Do you have any idea why? Btw, it looks like the array is sorted according to the standards.

Comment: This must be a dup somewhere `tab.sort( function(a,b){ return a-b })`

Comment: `The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**Javascript sort() not alphabetizing properly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571140/javascript-sort-not-alphabetizing-properly) or even better [**How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

Comment: It does work, the numbers are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: The answer is in tons of SO posts and searching google for your exact title gives the answer as well how to use `sort`  In addition please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include the desired behavior, a specific problem__ or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. __Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers__. See: How to create a [mcve]._"

Comment: @Fran Not a dup, we even don't know, what is wrong with the code. It's pure speculation to give a number order as an answer, it might be, that OP wants a reversed order, or what ever ...

Comment: @Teemu I doubt it! SO posts like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function and the actual documentation for it explain it well enough that one should be able to sort in any order preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `sort` method will sort the array that it has been called on alphabetically.

To get around this you need to pass `sort` a callback function that will sort the elements by their numerical value.

To achieve this you need to do the following:

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

let tab = [5, 15, 17, 3, 8, 11, 28, 6, 55, 7];
let sortedTab = tab.sort(sortNumber);
console.log(sortedTab);
```

Comment: Please close questions which have been answered over and over as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As Explained in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

That is, you should give `sort` the function that is to compare elements of the array, otherwise, your array will be sorted according to string Unicode code points.

This should work (sort in ascending order):

```
function compareFunction(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

// sort tab array using compareFunction to compare elements
tab.sort(compareFunction);
```